# make LWC's targetConfig's property mandatory

Tags: lightning-web-components, configuration, xml

How can I make some properties in the meta file mandatory?

I have defined a few properties in below format

```
<targetConfigs>
  <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <property name="somenumber" label="Some Number" type="Integer" default="0" />
  </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Although I have given a default value, but it will be a problem if some admin will delete the default value. (I have to make this property configurable for admins).
So, how to make the property mandatory?

I'm trying to find something similar to "Required Attributes" feature mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple_attributes.asp).

Note:- Most of my properties are either String (with free text and not with apex data source) or Integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something with your question, why can't you just add the `required` attribute to your property?

e.g.

```
<targetConfigs>
  <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <property name="somenumber" label="Some Number" type="Integer" default="0" required="true" />
  </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

For more info:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags covers this. Would be good to include link in answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Cook, It worked like a charm. 
Thanks PhilW for mentioning the documentation, I scanned it yesterday but somehow missed this feature ;)